# How to go through a list of installed programs and take out any line with Microsoft-related strings?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, findstr, list

This is on Windows 7 using command line and batch files.

I was looking to examine my program list and uninstall a good amount of junk and update a good amount of outdated programs. I used a wmic command to get a text document with every program, line-by-line. I want to remove every program from that list with "microsoft", "windows", or "visual" in the name. I'm trying to do this using the *findstr* command, and the /v option that makes it output only lines without a match. However, running the program I wrote finds no matches within the file so basically just copies it. I tried the wild characters as well in case it's the other characters around the word messing it up or something.

Here's an example of one of the lines in the file it's looking through: (LASTNAME-LAPTOP,Microsoft Office Excel Viewer,12.0.6612.1000)

The PATH is just a representation of the path to my flash drive folder, in the script it's the actual path to a folder with both RTF files inside it. It contained a space so I put quotes around the source and output.

Here is my program:

```
findstr /i /v ".microsoft. .windows. .visual." "E:\PATH\programs.rtf" > "E:\PATH\programs2.rtf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Running the program I wrote finds no matches within the file

> I used a wmic command to get a text document with every program, line-by-line.

From [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html):

> All output files are unicode text (convert to ASCII with [TYPE](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html))

This confuses `findstr` which expects ASCII as input, for example:

```
F:\test>findstr /i /v "microsoft windows visual" unicode.txt
 ■N a m e                                                                                                                       V e r s i o n

 V A I O   D a t a   R e s t o r e   T o o l                                                                                   1 . 6 . 0 . 1 3 1 4 0
 I n k s c a p e   0 . 9 1                                                                                                     0 . 9 1
 M S X M L   4 . 0   S P 3   P a r s e r   ( K B 2 7 5 8 6 9 4 )                                                               4 . 3 0 . 2 1 1 7 . 0
```

You can get around this using the following sequence of example commands:

```
wmic product get name,version > unicode.txt
type unicode.txt > programs.txt
findstr /i /v "microsoft windows visual" programs.txt > programs2.txt
```

Alternatively:

```
wmic product get name,version > programs.txt
type programs.txt | findstr /i /v "microsoft windows visual" > programs2.txt
```

Notes:

- Use plain text files (not RTF) as input to `findstr`.
- `type` is used to convert from Unicode to ASCII.
- The `.` characters are not need in the `findstr` command

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.